# Add data attribute to module html - Joomla 3.4.8

Tags: joomla-3.x, module

I'm trying to add `data-uk-sticky` attribute to a Joomla module that displays a sidebar menu (to make it sticky).

For that, I created an alternative layout by copying

```
/modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php
```

To:

```
/modules/mod_menu/tmpl/sticky.php
```

In the sticky.php file I wrapped the whole content in a div like:

```
<div data-uk-sticky><ul class="nav menu<?php echo $class_sfx;?>"<?php
```

In the module admin, I can now select Sticky in the Alternative Layout configuration.

However, when reloading the page I can't find the div I created. Why not?

I also tried copying the whole mod_menu to the template/html folder but the result is the same.

Comment: You say you've wrapped everything in a `div`, but are you sure you closed it with `</div>`?

Comment: Hello @Lodder, yes, I'm sure about that, I just didn't show the code.

Comment: Arn't you going to assign something to the `data-*` attribute, e.g., `data-uk-sticky="blah"`? Do you intent to make it a property? From your statements, you don't.

Comment: No, I'm leaving it empty as per http://getuikit.com/docs/sticky.html

Comment: This page has been abandoned.  If you have resolved the issue, please consider posting a complete and educational answer.  If you would still like support and have more details to share, please update your question.  If you are no longer seeking support and have no intention of progressing this page toward a system recognized resolution, you are welcome to delete your question.  Abandoned pages represent information dead ends for researchers.